# Publish 2 InfoPath forms as content types to one library?

Tags: content, infopath

We have to develop 8 infopath forms for use in a doc library. What these will be are various forms filled out for our patients. The reason we’re looking at a doc library over lists, is they want to be able to quickly go to a patient folder that would serve as a patient record to view all forms filled out for them, as well as upload scanned items.

So I had the idea to develop infopath forms and publish them as content types to the library. However, it seems that everytime I open the form, it wants to update it to the most recent one published, even though I published them as different content types. So here’s my scenario.

1. Develop Form A and publish as content type, named Form A, to my doc library.
2. Add the content type Form A to the doc library.
3. Test Form A and it opens as Form A and I can submit, etc
4. Develop Form B and publish as a content type, named Form B, to the same doc
   library.
5. Add the content type Form B to the doc library.
6. Test Form B and it opens and I can submit etc.
7. Under the New button you can now see both content types. If I click on Form A, then it opens but asks me to update my form, and when I do, it changes it to Form B. So I can never get two content types submitted, it always reverts to the one that’s most recently published.

What I'd like is to have the user have mulitple forms to submit and then it shows that they're of different content types so the admins will know what form it is at a glance, but they all submit as one content type.

Comment: When you created your second form, were you doing a "copy" and "paste" of the first infoform document?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thats what I did.
 
So I've resolved this. The piece I was missing was when I was publishing to my Form Template library, I was not naming the file after the libary URL, I was just putting the library URL.

Comment: This is funny. You wrote in 1) and 4) that you were publishing to doc library. Now you write about form lib.

Comment: Isn't the only difference between a form library and a document library that one has a default document like "page" or "word" and the other has a default of "form"?  Is there some *other* difference?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem though I strongly advise you to publish (from Infopath Designer) your Infopath XSN form templates (as content types) to a Sharepoint (form) library different from that to which you submit your Infopath data forms based on one of chosen templates.

Answer (score 0):

Publish both forms as content types to your **xsn template library**, and in the target Library that you want the xml forms to be submitted to (**these are the forms based on the template(xsn) the ones users complete in the browser**), add both content types from existing(because you have published them already) then you are done. You can now submit forms based on either content type to the same document Library.